# Can I bind read() function to type 'instance' in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

i'm learning BeautifulSoup and i encountered this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katy_Perry"
open_url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
read = open_url.read()
print(read)
```

This prints the html code of the page. But how can we use read() here ? Its a FileIO function and should be used along with the file object. but the variable "open_url" here isn't a file object.

```
print(type(open_url))
```

output:

```
<type 'instance'>
```

Obviously "open_url" isn't a file object, So what made it possible to bind read() to "open_url" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: `open` is an instance of an object, meaning it can have nearly everything binded to it (attributes and methods). Note: Rename your variable for something else as `open()` is a builtin function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print  both `open_url` you will see that `fp = socket._fileobject ..`

```
<addinfourl at 139707791457312 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f104303bd50>>
```

So you see the file object is actually a `socket._fileobject` which you can access with `open_url.fp`:

```
<socket._fileobject object at 0x7f104303bd50>
```

If you remove the first read call you will see that you can access the socket object and call *.read* on that directly, that is what happens when you call `open_url.read()` etc..:

```
open_url.fp.read()
```